# VS Code snippet: How do I make a camelCase variable transformation based on a CamelCase variable?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

**Goal**: In VS Code, I'm trying to create a snippet that takes "FooBar" and outputs "FooBar fooBar".

**Current Code**: I have "$1 ${1:camelcase}" for the body of my snippet. But it outputs "FooBar FooBar." I have tried a number of other options but none seem to work. I know it's probably something relatively simple that I'm missing.

**Question**: What is the correct syntax to make only the first letter of my variable name become lowercase?

Answer (score 3):

All you really need is the first letter and ignore the rest:

```
  "$1 ${1/(.)/${1:/downcase}/}",
```

or using the newer `camelcase` option:

```
  "$1 ${1/(.*)/${1:/camelcase}/}",
```

Answer (score 0):

you just split the string in two parts

```
${1/(.)(.*)/${1:/downcase}${2}/}
```